# Matrilineal descent & Zera Israel

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, matrilineal-descent

Would someone with Jewish heritage from a distant foremother on their maternal grandfather's side be considered Zera Yisrael?

In other words, does the person fit the definition of Zera Yisrael since their status as a Jewish person is in doubt, but it is acknowledged that they have Jewish ancestors?

Comment: They would not if they can be proven to be Jews

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, that may not work if its very distant.

Comment: @ariel where does it say that?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, it was Yevamos 17, but it's not at all clear that it would apply in general: א"ל לא זזו משם עד שעשאום עובדי כוכבים גמורים שנאמר בה' בגדו כי בנים זרים ילדו
http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=17&format=text

Comment: @ArielK I understood it as a horaas shaah

Comment: @Shmuel So you think the gemaras chashash there applies nowadays again? (I've been avoiding quoting that gemara ever since Ali's been around.)

Comment: @msh210, yes I am asking if the person fits the definition of Zera Yisrael since their status as a Jewish person is in doubt but it is acknowledged that they have Jewish ancestors. Thank you

Comment: Is Zera Yisrael a technical term?  I mean, I know what those words mean, but is it a halachic category or something?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/what-is-the-difference-between-gerim-and-nochrim
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convert_to_Judaism#Terminology

Comment: @MonicaCellio "Zera Yisrael" is essentially not a technical term or a halachic category. The term was concocted in part based on a responsum by R' Tzvi Hirsch Kalischer where he waxed poetic when discussing a reason to condone a Jewish father who wants to circumcise his non-Jewish child (especially since such a child would be more likely to want to convert in the future when compared with a typical child with no biologically Jewish parents). He suggested that if this child would eventually decide to convert, it will have been meritorious to take anticipatory action to prevent him from...

Comment: ... facing a painful circumcision as an adult. As an afterthought, he poetically described this preparatory action as a means of participating in a metaphysical rectification of sorts for the original corruption of the father's "holy seed" which is being returned to its holiness. The responsum indicates that such a conversion is only laudable if it is sincere and warranted on its own merits, implying that it's inappropriate to encourage conversions that should otherwise not be conducted. However, this responsum has recently been used to fuel an aggressively proactive conversion agenda.

Comment: The main point of that responsum, that it is good in general to take action now that would remove a hindrance from a potential future sincere convert, does not depend on whether the father is Jewish. A child being raised (present-tense) by a Jewish father might in some cases provide a circumstantial context and a home life that is more conducive to conversion (similar to a case where Jewish parents adopt and convert a non-Jewish child *al da'as beis din*). There does not seem to be any halachic relevance (in this regard) to whether an adult has a Jewish father, though.

Comment: @Fred, thanks for the explanation!  It would be great if that information could be summarized or linked in the question.

Comment: @MahaliaS ^^^^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Am I Jewish​​​?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52891/am-i-jewish)

Answer (score 2):

From the [intro to chapter 5 in זרע ישראל by Rav Amsalem](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=50709&st=&pgnum=335&hilite=), he describes Zera Yisrael as:

> ויש להם לרוב צד
>    יהדות ברור, שאביהם **או סבם או סבתם** וכדומה היו יהודים שנשאו נכריות

So he does include a Jewish grandparent in his definition. In almost every example after that, the book seems to uses the case of a Jewish father, but it seems that Rav Amsalem views it more broadly, with "צד יהדות ברור" (clearly somewhat subjective) as being the key deciding factor.

Comment: SkinnyJ, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for contributing this on-point answer! I hope you'll look around and find other questions of interest, perhaps starting with our collection of 100+ [tag:am-yisrael-jewish-nation] questions.

Comment: Although the OP doesn't really ask if "zera Yisrael" is a legitimate halachic category, I should mention that, from what I have read (a substantial amount) of R' Amsalem's book, almost none of the many sources he cites actually support his thesis that "zera Yisrael" is a real halachic category that deserves special accommodation wrt the laws of גרות (except for the opinion of [R' Uziel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben-Zion_Meir_Hai_Uziel), which is widely rejected by poskim).

Comment: You might have some valuable information to offer on [this recent question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57339/5323). cc @Fred

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, Zera Yisrael(Seed of Israel) IS a halachic concept, applicable to non-jews who are patrilineal descendants of Jews. That is, some forefather along their direct paternal lineage was halachically Jewish, whether it was one generation ago or a descendant of the Bnei Anusim of the inquisition period or anything in between. This can mean they are either direct paternal descendants or it can mean a distant forefather's mother was Jewish. However if the father is not a halakhic jew or paternal Zera Yisrael, the children are not Zera Yisrael.

So if the only Jewish heritage is on your *maternal* grandfather's side.. Even assuming so far that your maternal grandfather is a halachic Jew... it would at most make your mother a Zera Yisrael, but not you.

I understand there is a lot of debate today, especially in the area of conversion of descendants of Bnei Anusim and other 'Crypto-Jewish' populations, and ESPECIALLY among paternal "half-jews".. whether Zera Yisrael should have a special status for an expedited conversion or even just be fully accepted as Jews. I am not informed enough to speak further on that.

Still, if you are a potential convert with *any* Jewish heritage, or none at all for that matter, and you seriously want to become an official member of the tribe, you will be more than welcome.

Comment: Hayim, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for submitting this answer! It could be made much more valuable if you would [edit] in sources for your understandings. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: The nascent notion of "zera Yisrael" is sometimes attributed to responsa about the B'nei Anusim (e.g. Rashbash, §368). However, these responsa are not talking about children of Anusim fathers and non-Jewish mothers. Rather, they are talking about B'nei Anusim who are actual Jews.