# What is the difference between gerim, nochrim and zarim?

Tags: words, hebrew

What is the difference between gerim, nochrim and zarim? Both halachicly and denotatively.

Comment: Please [edit] in the context in which you see these terms and want them explained, as well as a bit more about what you mean by "halachicly and denotatively."

Comment: https://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/9346

Answer (score 7):

It depends on context, but in general there are two types of Gerim:

1) A Ger Tzedek (Righteous convert). That is a convert in the traditional sense.

2) A Ger Toshev (Dwelling convert). That category doesn't formally exist today, but the concept of it is a non-Jew who accepts the Seven Mitzvos of Noach. They have permission to live in Israel.

Typical usage of the word "Ger" denotes the former.

A Nochri would be a non-Jew. In some contexts it may seek to distinguish between a Ger Toshev and otherwise, but it means a foreigner.

A Zar (stranger) almost always means the term for a Jew who is not a Cohen.