# Yemeni manuscripts about the Hebrew expression - in Mishneh Torah Hilchot Avodah Zarah 9:4 - translated as "idolaters"

Tags: hebrew, rambam, avodah-zarah, mishneh-torah

I am an Italian Noahide.

in Mishneh Torah Hilchot-Avodah Zarah 9:4-, Rambam states that Christians are idolaters.

Now, in various editions of the work, including the one available on the Chabad website, unless I am mistaken, the Hebrew expression used by Rambam would be "ovedei kokhavim umazalot". However, I read that, according to the authoritative Yemeni manuscripts of the work, Rambam used the Hebrew expression “ovedei avodah zarah.”

Is what I read correct? And if it is, for what reasons is this textual variant found?

Comment: Many times the term _Avoda Zara_ was changed to _Kochavim Umazalot_ due to the censors that would take it out because they were idol worshipers. But if it said _Kochavim umazalot_ they would let it through since they didn't serve the stars and constellations.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47763/2394

Comment: Mechon Mamre's edition of Mishneh Torah, which it claims to be "לפי הנוסח של רוב כתבי היד התימניים" (based on majority of Yemenite manuscripts), [has](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/1409.htm#4) "עובדי עבודה זרה", as does [the Qafiḥ edition](https://net-sah.org/library/770) (which claims to be "עפ"י מספר כתבי יד היותר מדויקים ומהימנים של יהודי תימן", "based on the most accurate and reliable Yemenite manuscripts"), as can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqiDFWXhHR4-Bx_y4C_-1k5Pai1h2cz-/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: @TamirEvan 

Comment: "_Now, in various editions of the work, including the one available on the Chabad website, unless I am mistaken, the Hebrew expression used by Rambam would be 'ovedei kokhavim umazalot'._" It's more than that: [The edition brought by the Chabad website](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912368/jewish/Avodat-Kochavim-Chapter-Nine.htm#v4) has 'כְּנַעֲנִים'/'Canaanites' instead of 'נוצרים'/'Christians'.

Comment: "_in Mishneh Torah Hilchot-Avodah Zarah 9:4-, Rambam states that Christians are idolaters._" He does so also in [Ma'achalot Assurot 11:7](https://mechon-mamre.org/i/5211.htm#4)...

Comment: ...There, [the edition brought by the Chabad website](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968267/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-11.htm#v7) has "אוֹתָם הָעוֹבְדִים עַכּוּ''ם" ("those who worship false deities") instead, but [in the footnotes (No. 24)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/968267/jewish/Maachalot-Assurot-Chapter-11.htm#footnote24a968267) says "[t]he uncensored text reads, 'Christians, by contrast, are idolaters. It is forbidden to benefit....'".